# Unresolved symbol column - Scala Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, sbt, slick

I'm currently trying to create a table using slick and I'm baffled as to what import I'm missing as the examples I've seen don't seem to have a relevant looking import in them.

Currently the column, question mark and the O's are all unresolved.
Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong please?

Here is my table class:

```
package com.grimey.tabledefinitions
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import com.grimey.staticpage.StaticPage
import slick.lifted.Tag
import slick.model.Table

class StaticPageDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[StaticPage](tag, "static_page") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def pageType = column[String]("page_type")
  def contentHtml = column[String]("content_html")

  def * = (id.?, pageType, contentHtml) <>(StaticPage, StaticPage.unapply _)
}
```

And here is my build.sbt:

```
name := """grimey-cms"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

fork in run := true
```

And finally, here is the case class I'm using for the table:

```
package com.grimey.staticpage

import java.time.LocalDateTime

case class StaticPage(id: Long, htmlContent: String, pageType: String,
                      created: LocalDateTime, updated: LocalDateTime)
```

I bet it's something really silly :)

Comment: add the following import, `slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `O` object is from the table and it varies driver to driver.  Some drivers may not support certain column options supported by others.  Therefore you will need to import the column options that are specific to your database - MySQL in this case:

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that import does not have any impact. I'm still getting unresolved errors for the slick specific parts of the code in StaticPageDef.scala.

Comment: Hi there... remove the other two imports there: `import slick.lifted.Tag` and
`import slick.model.Table` and you should be all set. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may check this full tutorial on how to use Play + Slick + MySQL: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/

Or you may just navigate through the code: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That first link is the one I was using first. Note that it doesn't show any imports or mentions where the column functions are coming from. Other tutorials I've found have done the same thing. Which is why I swallowed my pride and created this question.
I don't think I've seen that particular github repo, so I'll dig through and hopefully get to the bottom of where these slick functions\object are coming from :)